# How can I achieve this :hover image overlay

Tags: hover, overlay

I came across this site: http://gatilho.com/

I love the blue overlay and site title that slides down on image hover but I can't seem to figure out how it's done. I want the transition too.

Any suggestions?
Is it just CSS or jQuery too?

Thanks!

(p.s. I'm not looking to rip it off just like it so I want to figure out how!)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source code, it looks like they're using http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex5/overlapcontent.htm